# How to manage logincontroller in tabbar based ios application?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate, rootview

I have a  tabbar based application and it has login & signup as well.

Currently my `rootviecontroller` is loginVc i.e 
`navigationcntl -> loginVC`.

After successful login, user goes to the 3rd tab inside the application.

Each tab inside shows data based on valid user (so token is checked inside as well).

If token is expired, user is supposed to be sent back to login.

I want to know the correct flow for the apllication from login to logout? Should login be used as modal and tabcontroller as rootview?

Comment: This depends on the user experience prioritisation in your application and the use cases which will impact the flow. I will always keep the Login VC out side Tab Controller. This will help to release the Tab bar on session expiry. Also will reduce several use case handling.

Comment: In our app, the user has to be authenticated in order to use the app so login is critical and needs to check for token on every tab. If possible, share the snippet of code.

Comment: This seems like a big project to me. What use case you want to cover in the snippet? It is a simple VC flow you need to implement. If you have any issues in flow then please ask that question and people will be happy to answer.

Comment: Just help to figure out the correct approach from login to logout in tabbar based application? Modal login and tabbar as rootview

Comment: Could you please put together the sample application for the use case which you are using at present? I will modify it with the inputs.